# Little-endian hex in GHKit diagnostic, why?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing

In the context of iPhone programming, I am using the GHKit for unit testing (gabriel / gh-unit on github).

Here is a failing test assertion :

```
GHAssertEquals(150, 15, @"someLimit");
```

and here is the diagnostic from GHKit (shows up in the Simulator and in the Xcode Console) :

```
    2009-07-25 22:41:12.553 UnitTests[38404:3f07] Exception: '<96000000>' should be equal to '<0f000000>' +/-'(null)'. someLimit
```

Manifestly, GHKit displays the offending values in little-endian hex.

OK, I can convert to integer values, but why so? 
Is this a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obtained the answer from the author of GHKit, in the ghunit google groups thread [1](http://groups.google.com/group/ghunit/browse_thread/thread/b2c2a33d92b17611),
where he wrote ...

Perhaps we need some macros for testing primitives like:

GHAssertEqualIntegers
   GHAssertEqualInts
   GHAssertEqualDoubles
   GHAssertEqualFloats